# How to write data to specific position in a TXT file?

Tags: file, fortran

I want to change part of a text file. The file's contents follow:

```
PLANE
CV = 1.4, PRINT = 1
Ks = 3.17, G = 120.67, DIST = 0.34, POR = 0.456, ROCK = 0.3
PLANE
```

I want to replace the `ks=3.17` part with a random number. More specifically, the text file is the input to another executable, and I want to modify the Ks value, run the executable, modify the Ks value again, and so on.

Comment: Using sed for this from a shell script is easier than using fortran.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably better ways of doing it, but this works. It writes a new output file changing the Ks value to 9.99.

```
Program modify_value

implicit none

character(len=100) :: row
integer :: j
real :: Ks

Ks = 9.99

open(unit=1,file='data.txt',status='old')
open(unit=2,file='data_modified.txt',status='unknown')

do j=1,4
  read(1,'(a)') row
  if (j==3) then
    write(2,'(a,F5.2,a)') row(1:4), Ks, trim(row(10:))
  else
    write(2,'(a)') trim(row)
  end if
end do

close(1)
close(2)

End Program
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have strong reason to use fortran for this task?  The task you described in the last paragraph may be accomplished with other languages with less hustle.  For example if you write a python script like below,

```
import os, random

# repeat 10 times
for i in range(10):

    # generate random Ks with Normal distribution, mean=3.17, stdev=1
    ks = random.normalvariate(3.17,1)

    # write input file
    with open('inp.txt','w') as f:

        f.write( 
"""PLANE
CV = 1.4, PRINT = 1
Ks = %4.2f, G = 120.67, DIST = 0.34, POR = 0.456, ROCK = 0.3
PLANE""" % ks )


    # run the program
    os.system("a.exe")
```

Given sample fortran program like this,

```
program test
  character(len=80) :: line
  open(10,file='inp.txt',status='old')
  do i=1,4
  read(10,'(a)') line
  write(*,*) trim(line)
  enddo
end program
```

You will get

```
$ python test.py
 PLANE
 CV = 1.4, PRINT = 1
 Ks = 1.21, G = 120.67, DIST = 0.34, POR = 0.456, ROCK = 0.3
 PLANE
 PLANE
 CV = 1.4, PRINT = 1
 Ks = 3.08, G = 120.67, DIST = 0.34, POR = 0.456, ROCK = 0.3
 PLANE
 PLANE
 CV = 1.4, PRINT = 1
 Ks = 4.55, G = 120.67, DIST = 0.34, POR = 0.456, ROCK = 0.3
 PLANE
 PLANE
 CV = 1.4, PRINT = 1
 Ks = 4.10, G = 120.67, DIST = 0.34, POR = 0.456, ROCK = 0.3
 PLANE
 PLANE
 CV = 1.4, PRINT = 1
 Ks = 2.24, G = 120.67, DIST = 0.34, POR = 0.456, ROCK = 0.3
 PLANE
 PLANE
 CV = 1.4, PRINT = 1
 Ks = 4.62, G = 120.67, DIST = 0.34, POR = 0.456, ROCK = 0.3
 PLANE
 PLANE
 CV = 1.4, PRINT = 1
 Ks = 2.76, G = 120.67, DIST = 0.34, POR = 0.456, ROCK = 0.3
 PLANE
 PLANE
 CV = 1.4, PRINT = 1
 Ks = 2.69, G = 120.67, DIST = 0.34, POR = 0.456, ROCK = 0.3
 PLANE
 PLANE
 CV = 1.4, PRINT = 1
 Ks = 4.58, G = 120.67, DIST = 0.34, POR = 0.456, ROCK = 0.3
 PLANE
 PLANE
 CV = 1.4, PRINT = 1
 Ks = 3.32, G = 120.67, DIST = 0.34, POR = 0.456, ROCK = 0.3
 PLANE
```

Comment: A Fortran program with EXECUTE_COMMAND_LINE command and calling some random number function and similar write wouldn't actually be any longer.